# Knowing the password, how to obtain recovery key from bitlocker partition?

Tags: disk-encryption

My bitlocker-encrypted Windows wont start up with the password, instead it asks for the recovery key. However, I can mount the partition and access files -albeit readonly- using dislocker on ubuntu.

Can I obtain the recovery key using dislocker?

Or how can I fix the partition?

Comment: "Can I obtain the recovery key using dislocker?" - The only way to solve your problem is with the recovery key, you will be unable to recover the recovery key, with dislocker.  At this point since you have the password you can backup the data.  Since the files themselfs are not encrypted, if you move the files to another drive, they will not be encrypted.